# add title attribute to continue reading link (wp)

Tags: php, wordpress, attributes, title

I have a 'Continue Reading' function that looks like this:

```
function twentyten_continue_reading_link() {
global $id;
return ' <span class="readmore"><a href="'. get_permalink($id) . '">' . __( 'Read More <span class="meta-nav">&#187;</span>', 'twentyten' ) . '</a></span>';
}
```

I want to add a title attribute, which I think should look something like this

```
title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"
```

but I'm not sure exactly how to insert the title in the above function to get it to work correctly. Can somebody help me get the syntax right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute#Example

`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute( array('before' => 'Permalink to: ', 'after' => '')); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>`

Since you want to return it, you probably need something like this:

```
return '<a href="' . get_permalink(); . ' title="' . the_title_attribute( array('echo' => 0, 'before' => 'Permalink to: ', 'after' => '')) . the_title() . '>';
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but I am getting a parse error (unexpected '.')

Comment: Do you know where I made the mistake?

Comment: function twentyten_continue_reading_link() {
global $id;
 return ' <span class="readmore"><a href="'. get_permalink($id) . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( array('echo' => 0, 'before' => 'Permalink to: ', 'after' => '')); . the_title() . '>' . __( 'Read More <span class="meta-nav">&#187;</span>', 'twentyten' ) . '</a></span>';
}

Comment: @Sarah There's a stray semicolon in the middle of the line. Sorry about that. I've edited my example to remove it.